# Index layout: subitems on the same line as entries

Tags: formatting, indexing, imakeidx

I am trying to get this kind of index :

[image]

I am using `book` documentclass and `imakeidx`.

Does anyone know how to get this kind of aspect?

I guess it has to do with the `.ist` file, but I don't really know if my subitems are `item_x1`, `item_1` or `item_01`.

```
headings_flag 1
delim_0 "}\\hspace{0pt},\\hspace{6pt}"
delim_1 "\\hspace{0pt},\\hspace{5pt}"
delim_2 "\\hspace{0pt},\\hspace{4pt}"
delim_t "."
item_0 " \\item {  " 
item_x1 "},\\subitem }"
item_1 "}\\subitem "
item_01 "}\\subitem "
```

Thank you all in advance !

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill sorry about this, I usually think about it, a little forgetfulness on my side on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.ind` auxiliary file produced by `makeindex` program is just a `theindex` environment and its contents is similar to

```
\begin{theindex}
<heading>
  \item <level 0 entry>, <page>.
    \subitem <level 1 entry>, <page>.
    \subitem <level 1 entry>, <page>.

  \indexspace

<more entries>
\end{theindex}
```

So it is the `\subitem` that caused the newline before every level 1 entry. Since `\subitem` is a latex macro normally provided by document class, you can just redefine it. In the following example, I list the original definitions from document class `article` and redefine them to fulfill your requirement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options= -s inline-subitems.ist]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@idxitem{\par}
\renewcommand\subitem{}

% \newcommand\@idxitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@}
% \item is let to \@idxitem at \begin{theindex}
% \newcommand\subitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{20\p@}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
First entry group%
\index{entry}\index{alpha!beta}\index{alpha!gamma}\index{alpha!eta}

Second entry group%
\index{entry!a}\index{entry!b}\index{entry!c}\index{entry!d}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

```
% inline-subitems.ist
headings_flag 1
delim_0 "}, "
delim_1 ", "
delim_2 ", "
delim_t "."
item_0 "\n  \\item \\textbf{"
item_1 "\n    \\subitem "
item_01 "\n    \\subitem "
item_x1 "}.\n    \\subitem "
```

[image]

Comment: It is working perfectly, thank you !